# Ordering by First Foreign Key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Consider these two simple models:

```py
from django.db import models

class Foo( models.Model ):
  pass

class Bar( models.Model ):
  time = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True )
  foo = models.ForeignKey(
    Foo,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
    related_name='bars'
  )
```

How can I order `Foo` objects by first related `Bar` object?

```py
Foo.objects.order_by('-bars.first__time')
```

Comment: Define "first". Records are unorded. Perhaps you want the *smallest* `time`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what `Model.some_related_objects.first()` do then?

Comment: it just returns the first record that the database writes in it answer, but that record can each time be different. Especially after updates/deletes/inserts, it happens that `.first()` is something else. A `QuerySet` is ordered in the sense that the database can not write all elements at once, but besides that there is no order.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okay, in this case I want to order `Foo` objects by related 'Bar' object with smallest time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the "first" is the `Bar` object with the "*oldest*" time, we can first `.annotate(..)` our `Foo` objects, and then order on that minimum. We thus first annotate with [**`Min(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#min), and then use that annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Min

Foo.objects.annotate(
    min_time=Min('bars__time')
).order_by('-min_time')
```